# create a master_id to identify dupes in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

For business reason I have a table with pictures information and their could be duplicated, but we cant delete the dupes. Every image has a image_id so we can have the same picture with more than 1 image_id (not nice at all).

For other task I need to avoid to select the same picture to display, so I would like to create a new column to define a "master_id", like the min image_id of the same picture.

Right now, Im able to query/detect which of them are dupes joining the table with itself on the fields with picture information ->

[image: Table of dupes].

But for instance, row 4 it should not appear because rows 2 and 3 already create that, and will affect the update of the table in the master_id column.

Any idea how to create easily this master_id column?

The final output of rows 2,3 and 4 should look something like:

```
image_id  | master_id
11397     | NULL
12226     | 11397
12232     | 11397
```

Comment: Can you share the query you used to generate the results in the image?

Answer (score 0):

You can to create realtionship with a external table, to group the images in a reference.

For example:

In a hipotetic cenary, create table DocumentVersion and in this table you group the images:

```
CREATE TABLE document_version (int id, varchar description)
```

In the next step, create the ImageDocumentVersion

```
CREATE TABLE image_document_version (int id, fk_document_version)
```

In your query for select images you reffer the document version. And when you need to select the most recent image, reffer the document version selecting the max id of the image

```
SELECT max(id) FROM image_document_version WHERE fk_document_version = [[id of document]]
```

I hope to help.
Reggards.